# perl expression find & replace to modify an external function definition

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use perl to remove parameters from a function definition?  eg if my file contains the following text:

```
var1 = myfunc(sss,'ROW DRILL',1,1,0);
var2 = myfunc(fff,'COL DRILL',1,1,0);
var3 = myfunc(anyAlphaNum123,'anyAlphaNum123 or space',1,1,0);
donotcapture=myfunc2(rr,'some string',1,1,0);
```

I need to change it so that it becomes:

```
var1 = myfunc(sss,'ROW DRILL');
var2 = myfunc(fff,'COL DRILL');
var3 = myfunc(anyAlphaNum123,'anyAlphaNum123 or space');
donotcapture=myfunc2(rr,'some string',1,1,0);
```

Essentially just removing `,1,1,0` from all instances where `myfunc` is called, but preserving the first two parameters.

I have tried the following, but this approach would mean I have to write rules for each permutation...

```
perl -pi -w -e "s/myfunc\(rr,'COL SUBSET',1,1,0\)/myfunc\(rr,'COL SUBSET'\)/g;" *.txt
```

Comment: Do you always call the function with the same values (`,1,1,0`)?

Comment: yes, it's nearly all ,1,1,0.

Comment: why the close votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In order to reduce complexity, generalize your regex, using flexible regexes.

  - The regex for "anything between `(` and `,`, except `,`  " : `\(([^,]+),`
  - The regex for "anything between `'` and `'`, except `'` " : `\'([^']+)\'`
- In order to get the output right for the specific input (in spite of the flexibility),
  use capture groups, i.e. `(...)`.
  They populate variables, which you can use as `$1` in the substitution.
- To prevent matching functions with names ending in your functions name, e.g. `notmyfunc()`,
  use the regex for word boundary, i.e. `\b`.
- Ikegamis edit (separated to keep visible what you and I learned the hard way):

  - Avoid double-quotes for the program argument.
    It's just asking for trouble and requires so much extra escaping.
    Note that `\x27` is a single quote when used inside double-quotes or regex literals.
    `\'` -> `\x27`
  - Only use one capture group `(myfunc\([^,]+,\x27[^\x27]+\x27)`
  - Remove the `;`, which is not needed for a single statement.
  - Add a `.` to the input file wildcard, assuming you actually meant it like that.

Working code
(Comparing to chat note the `\((`; the backslash got lost, eaten by the chat I believe.):

```
perl -pi -w -e "s/(\bmyfunc)\(([^,]+),\'([^']+)\'(?:,\d+){3}\)/\$1\(\$2,\'\$3\'\)/g;" *txt
```

Ikegamis nice edit
(The detail which was so time-consuming in our chat is not easily visible anymore,
because the `(` for the capture group was moved somewhere else.):

```
perl -i -wpe's/\b(myfunc\([^,]+,\x27[^\x27]+\x27)(?:,\d+){3}\)/$1)/g' *.txt
```

Input:

```
var1 = myfunc(sss,'ROW DRILL',1,1,0);
var2 = myfunc(fff,'COL DRILL',1,1,0);
var3 = myfunc(s,'ROW SUBSET',1,1,0);
var4 = myfunc(rr,'COL SUBSET',1,1,0);
var5 = myfunc(rr,'COL SUBSET',2,12,50); with different values
var6 = notmyfunc(rr,'COL SUBSET',1,1,0); tricky differet name
var1 = myfunc(sss,'ROW DRILL',1,1,0);
var2 = myfunc(fff,'COL DRILL',1,1,0);
var3 = myfunc(anyAlphaNum123,'anyAlphaNum123 or space',1,1,0);
donotcapture=myfunc2(rr,'some string',1,1,0);
```

Output (version "even more relaxed"):

```
var1 = myfunc(sss,'ROW DRILL');
var2 = myfunc(fff,'COL DRILL');
var3 = myfunc(s,'ROW SUBSET');
var4 = myfunc(rr,'COL SUBSET');
var5 = myfunc(rr,'COL SUBSET'); with different values
var6 = notmyfunc(rr,'COL SUBSET',1,1,0); tricky differet name
var1 = myfunc(sss,'ROW DRILL');
var2 = myfunc(fff,'COL DRILL');
var3 = myfunc(anyAlphaNum123,'anyAlphaNum123 or space');
donotcapture=myfunc2(rr,'some string',1,1,0);
```

Lessons learned:

- I made a habit of creating regexes as tightly fitting the input as possible.
  But that caught us/me unprepared, when applied to sample input by someone inexperienced with regexes. (Absolutely no blame on you.)
- Posting code-quotes into chat is dangerous, be careful with `\`.

Comment: So it's still necessary to list the input string permutations for the second parameter? `(COL|ROW) (SUBSET|DRILL)`

Comment: That is to make the regex "tight" to your sample input. If you are sure that is not need you can probably simplify to "[A-Z ]+" or something. I updated the answer to cover that.

Comment: ok I tried with the updated answer (thanks for that) but it's not picking up the matches, will keep testing (here is my exact string:`perl -pi -w -e "s/(\bgetniteml)\(([sfr]+),\'([A-Z ]+)\'(?:,\d+){3}\)/\$1\(\$2,\'\$3\'\)/g;" d_*.sas`  )

Comment: What do you mean by "not picking up the matches" ? Do you want to provide more sample input? Is there any other expected result, apart from the file content changes? Something for which the matched parameters are needed maybe?

Comment: I mean the file isn't changing (am tracking it with git), it could be an issue my end, still testing :-)

Comment: Hmm, to prevent misunderstanding, I admit I tested `perl -p -w -e "s/(\bmyfunc)\(([sfr]+),\'([A-Z ]+)\'(?:,\d+){3}\)/\$1\(\$2,\'\$3\'\)/g;"`, i.e. without `-i` and filename. Then pasted the test lines. Will change that by making at least one test file and help testting.

Comment: Tested as `perl -pi -w -e "s/(\bmyfunc)\(([sfr]+),\'([A-Z ]+)\'(?:,\d+){3}\)/\$1\(\$2,\'\$3\'\)/g;" input*.txt` with two identical input.txt and input2.txt. Both were changed as desired, I believe.

Comment: I am on windows, GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (i686-pc-msys) and perl, v5.8.8 built for msys-64int.

Comment: I'm on mac OS Sierra

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146964/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-allan-bowe).

Comment: If you join me in chat, I could help to probe the regex-flavor of your environment. By making several experiments to verifiy all the little constructs I used. Otherwise that is what I recommend you to do, in order to home in on the problem.

Comment: Upper case  / lower case. `[A-Z ]+ `does not match `varname‌` etc.

Comment: thanks for taking the time in chat to really solve my problem, and also giving advice as to how to ask a better question too :-)

Comment: My pleasure. :-)

Comment: `\K` avoids captures altogether: `perl -i -wpe's/\bmyfunc\([^,]+,\x27[^\x27]+\x27\K[^)]+//g' *.txt`

Comment: @ikegami `Unrecognized escape \K passed through at -e line 1.` and it prevents the desired replacing.

Comment: Yeah, that's because you are using a 15 year old version. The OP didn't mention they were using an archaic version, so the assumption is that they aren't.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the trick with the `\x27`, I always felt I wanted to use single quotes (for precisely your reason), but never got them working if any single quote occurred anywhere inside.

Comment: @ikegami Also thanks for the perl version hint. Yes, I believe the version on this machine has started the petrification process. Time to update.

Comment: "Escape" single quotes by replacing them with `'\''`. That said, most single quotes inside Perl programs can be avoided. And fortunately, those that can't are usually one double-quotes. That allows the use of `\x27` instead of `'\''`, which has the bonus of not requiring modification if moved from `-e` to a file